# Calling a segue programatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I want to call a segue in swift on the condition that all the fields of the form are filled in. 
I tried using the following code :

```
 let vc = TargetViewController()
                        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true )
```

I am not using a nib, and hence have tried to use this without the nib option.
It opens a blank screen, but does not display the contents of the target view controller.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try This

```
if(Your Condition)
    {
        var View:ViewController2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("") as ViewController2
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(View, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method on `UIViewController` `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(_:sender:)` use this to test if segue can be performed. And If not return `false` from this method.

Comment: Thanks its Working but on Button click, it performs the 'shouldPerformSegue' func first and then '@IBAction' func buttonClicked. I need it to run the buttonClick function first because i'm checking the condition on which the segue should perform there. `override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == "MoveToDashboard" {
            if result1 == 0 || result2 == 0 {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }`